# CS7036: No argument given that corresponds to... (line of code that previously worked suddenly not working)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a line of code that worked to help move a player across my canvas (I'm doing this in unity using c#) It worked perfectly for horizontal, I copy pasted it, changed horizontal to vertical, switched the x axis and y axis and no I'm getting this error. It's driving me insane -- I'm not sure if there's some totally obvious answer I'm not seeing, but I've finally had enough and am looking for help.

I've switched from Vector3 to Vector2, tried rewriting the code from scratch in case I missed anything, tried copy-pasting from the original code, looked up various fixes to this same code error on different forums, etc.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") < -0.5f)
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0f));
    }

    if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < -0.5f)
    {
        transform.Translate(0f, new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
    }
}
```

This should allow the player to move not only left and right, but up and down as well. The error says there is no argument that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'y' of 'Vector2.Vector2(float,float)' -- but it worked just fine for the x axis!

Answer (score 1):

Just need to move the 0f inside the new Vector instead of inside the transform.Translate()

```
if (Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") > 0.5f || Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") < -0.5f)
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector2(0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
        }
```

Comment: Aghh thank you so much!!! That was driving me crazy. I knew it was a simple fix but I'm sick so my brain's only working at like 60% capacity.

Comment: Happy to help :)